# Excel 2016- Table will add a new row when the sheet is unprotected, but won't when it is protected

Tags: excel-2016, excel-tables

I have a table that covers columns C:N starting on row 19. When the sheet is unprotected and I add a new  row then the table automatically expands. When the sheet is protected the table does not automatically expand. Ideally I need the sheet locking because I have some formulas in column L:N and in  rows 1-14 that I don't want the user to accidentally change/erase/destroy.

Is there a way to protect the worksheet but still allow the table to expand to a new row or to protect the columns/rows/cells that contain the formulas that I don't want them to be able to access.

Thanks

I have googled a few solutions and ideally I want to stay away from having a button that unlocks the worksheet temporarily, and the other solutions that require VBA that don't seem to work, I'm wondering if that's due to the version of excel I am using (2016).